# Memory alignment causes crash using Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory-alignment

While performing a re-write of some existing code to better stream line it I encountered a crash during my testing which I narrowed down to a memory alignment issue but I am not sure how to fix it without masking the problem.  Is there a compiler primitive that I might need.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.

I have two files.

FileA.cpp

```
class ClassA : public baseClass
{
public: 
A() throw();
~A() throw();

virtual int Init() throw();
virtual int Start() throw();
virtual int Stop() throw();
virtual void Cleanup() throw();

public:
int *pap;
HANDLE m_evTimerStop;
    unsigned char m_ctrl;
CAtlList<int> m_list;
}
```

In FileA.cpp, when I access m_list, all is well.

In FileB.cpp I have declared a global variable

```
extern ClassA g_pCA;
```

So if some function goes to access m_list:

g_pCA->m_list.RemoveAt(pos);

It crashes.  If I call:
   g_pCA->m_list.GetCount();

In FileA, the count would be the correct number, say 10 elements.  But in FileB, the count is some random large number sometimes negative.  You get the picture.

So I managed to track this to the fact that m_list in file A.cpp is at address 0x9caba5 for example, but in file B.cpp, m_list is at 0x9caba8.  There is a 3 byte difference which made me suspect memory alignment.

If I move m_list above the m_ctrl, the problem goes away, and the addresses match across the files.

Or if I changed m_ctrl from an unsigned char to an int again the problem is obviously fixed due to alignment.

What I don't understand is why is the compiler in the different files applying different memory alignment rules.

Any compiler flags to resolve this?

Thank you....Amro

Comment: You don't happen to have a `pragma pack(1)` somewhere in your header files, by any chance? And that's NOT included in some other header?

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty certain that "FileA.cpp" does have a `#pragma pack(1)` included somewhere, that isn't being included in "FileB.cpp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my guess about `#pragma pack` is correct, the solution is to "only pack the structures that actually need it" by doing something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct something_that_needs_to_be_packed
{
   .... 
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Now your data that NEEDS to be packed will be so, but other data structure won't be affected. Which is how you'll want it, since packing and having unaligned data is a bad idea for several reasons, including performance, ability to reliably use the data in a multithreaded system, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.  I did some restructuring of some .h files to address circular inclusion and in the solution, loe and behold there was a #pragma(push,1) which I took out with a structure, but the pop was left behind.